# Returning unnecessary empty stings in Match Case Scala

Tags: spring, scala, switch-statement, match

I have written some code that does not seem to be good practice. The code works, but is kind of a mess. I'm not used to the `Some()` and `Option()`. How can I reduce the amount of empty strings returned?

Here is the code

```
private def creatEvent(
          req: Request,
          tstamp: Date,
          ID: String,
          DB: Item,
          Drop: Item
  ): Unit = {
    val itemExpired: String = {
      Option(DB) match {
        case Some(item) =>
          Option(item.expires) match {
            case Some(expires) =>
              if (service.hasExpired(expires))
                " item expired."
              else
                ""
            case None =>
              ""
          }
        case None =>
          ""
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `Option` at all? Why not just test the objects directly? `service.hasExpired(DB.item.expires)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there is an actual need to wrap `DB` and `item.expires` into `Option`s (even though I have feeling that there isn't), here is a variant without redundant `""`s:

```
val itemExpired: String = {
  val hasExpired = Option(DB).flatMap(item => Option(item.expires))
    .exists(service.hasExpired)
  if (hasExpired) " item expired." else ""
}
```

Comment: It ran in the tests so I think this will be good. If you like, could you maybe explain a bit how this works? :D

Comment: @Jonaslav this is functional programming where we use HOFs. (higher-order functions) Google and learn about it. What you have is an "imperative" style which is discouraged in the Scala community

Comment: @Jonaslav, I'm sorry, I don't have time to go into details, but I'd suggest to simply study the [Scaladoc for Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) (especially for the operators that I used).

Alternatively, this (kind of old, but still valid) article contains "The Ultimate Scala Option Cheat Sheet": https://www.originate.com/thinking/idiomatic-scala-your-options-do-not-match

Generally, handling of `Option`s is very standard thing in Scala that should be covered by almost any Scala learning resources.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `Option` here at all? Do you expect that things you are wrapping into it could be null?

The best solution is to just *never send nulls around* in scala at all.
Then you could just write:

```
if (service.hasExpired(DB.expires)) "item expired" else ""
```

If it is a possibility that either DB or DB.expires could be null, and you cannot fix that code, then `flatMap` is your friend:

```
def exp(it: Item) = Option(it).map(_.expires).flatMap(Option.apply)
if (exp(DB).exists(service.hasExpired)) "item expired" else ""
```

or just

```
Option(DB)
.map(_.expires)
.flatMap(Option.apply)
.map(service.hasExpired)
.filter(identity)
.fold("")(_ => "item expired")
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you're not used to FP and Scala, but still among your question and all the answers, I can't understand why you should use empty strings? it's actually useless, it has no value. This kind of default values and using if/else expressions to determine weather the value is meaningful or meaningless is actually considered to be a bad practice in Scala. I would highly recommend you to use Options instead of empty strings:

```scala
val itemExpiredEvent: Option[String] = {
  Option(DB)
    .flatMap(item => Option(item.expires))
    .map(service.hasExpired)
    .flatMap {
      case true => Some("item expired")
      case _ => None
    }
}
```

So imagine this way, if you get `None` out of this, it's the empty string scenarios, otherwise, you have your value.

Let's compare the two approaches:

```scala
// if an events's value is not empty, we would send it to some server
// first approach
val event: String = getEvent(...)
if (event != "") {
  someClient.sendEvent(event)
} else {
  fallback // else logic, default or fallback value or something here
}

// this approach
val eventOpt: Option[String] = getEvent(...)
eventOpt
  .map(someClient.sendEvent)
  .getOrElse(fallback)

// if you do not want to cover else branch:
val event: String = getEvent(...)
if (event.nonEmpty) {
  someClient.sendEvent(event)
} // if blocks without else are very discouraged in Scala

// this approach
val eventOpt: Option[String] = getEvent(...)
eventOpt.map(someClient.sendEvent)
// or if sendEvent method returns Unit
eventOpt.foreach(someClient.sendEvent)
```

Comment: Note that you could also do `Option(DB).flatMap(item => Option(item.expires)).filter(service.hasExpired).map(_ => "item expired")`. (Though I'm not sure if there are more valid reasons than just my personal taste to prefer that over your suggestion.)

Comment: @MartinHH Sure, personally I would've also used that over the code in the answer, but I thought that's a bit clearer for a beginner.